How to convert Integer to Decimal datatype in Guidewire?
We found code to convert 'Integer to Char' in article : https://partner.guidewire.com/s/article/How-to-change-a-column-datatype-with-IDatamodel
As per our project need, we need to convert datatype from Integer to Decimal. Requesting help .

Please edit your question and add a tag for the programming language. From a quick search, it appears to be Gosu, and according to the docs, "Java compatible, so you can use Java types, extend Java types, and implement Java interfaces". If that's the case, it might also be helpful to add Gosu and Java as tags.

Also, How to Convert Integer to Decimal in Java may be helpful.

You should probably improve your question. I gather that you'd like to convert a column in the DB from a Integer value to a Decimal. Please add more context. The best advice I can give you now is to write a DB upgrade trigger and play around with the functionality in a backup database. Read this documentation (and child articles) to understand how upgrade triggers work. https://docs.guidewire.com/self-managed/cc/upgrade/1012/topics/db/c_abu1977602.html?hl=upgrading,triggers,upgrade

I could not access the article but from what I understood give it a try:
var integer  = 1
var decimal = Double.valueOf(integer)
print(integer)
print(decimal)

